# disable future dates in vue3 using vue-2 datepicker?

Tags: vue.js

How can I disable future dates while using date range?

```html
<date-picker
 v-model="params.range"
 type="date"
 value-type="format"
 format="YYYY-MM-DD"
 range
 placeholder="Filter by date range"
/>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `disabled-date` prop to provide a function telling if a date should be disabled or not.

From the `vue2-datepicker` documentation [demo](https://mengxiong10.github.io/vue2-datepicker/index.html#DisabledDateTime) ([source code](https://github.com/mengxiong10/vue2-datepicker/blob/master/example/demo/DisabledDateTime.vue))

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <p>Not before than today and not after than a week</p>
    <date-picker
      v-model="value1"
      :default-value="new Date()"
      :disabled-date="disabledAfterToday"
    ></date-picker>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      value1: new Date(),
    };
  },
  methods: {
    disabledAfterToday(date) {
      const today = new Date();
      today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
      return date > today
    },
  },
};
</script>
```